# Tilda на собственном домене блокирует yandex карты

Tags: tilda

Возникла проблема с картами на тильде.
Используем стандартный блок, ключ api прописан, карта прогружается, метки добавляются. На собственном домене тильды .ws
Далее мы включаем собственный домен с https, всё проходит успешно, сайт переехал на наш домен. Но теперь вместо карт серый фон.
Ошибка в скрипте tilda-map-1.0.min.js

https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU&coordorder=latlong&onload=t_handleYandexApiReady_647956303&apikey=xxxxxxxxxxx
Request Method:
GET
Status Code:
403 Forbidden
Remote Address:
87.250.251.134:443
Referrer Policy:
strict-origin-when-cross-origin

```
function t_appendYandexMap(recid, key) {
if ("object" == typeof ymaps && "function" == typeof ymaps.Map)
    t_handleYandexApiReady(recid);
else if (window.yandexmapsapiiscalled)
    setTimeout((function() {
        t_appendYandexMap(recid, key)
    }
    ), 1e3);
else {
    var runfunc = "window.t_handleYandexApiReady_" + recid + ' = function () { return t_handleYandexApiReady("' + recid + '") }';
    eval(runfunc);
    var mapLang = ""
      , tildaMapElement = document.querySelector("#rec" + recid + " .t-map")
      , tildaMapElAttr = tildaMapElement.getAttribute("data-map-language");
    if (tildaMapElement)
        switch (tildaMapElAttr) {
        case "EN":
            mapLang = "en_US";
            break;
        default:
            mapLang = "ru_RU"
        }
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript",
    script.src = "https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=" + mapLang + "&coordorder=latlong&onload=t_handleYandexApiReady_" + recid,
    key && (script.src += "&apikey=" + key),
    document.body.appendChild(script), (вот здесь ошибка отображается в браузере)
    window.yandexmapsapiiscalled = !0
}
```

Как решить проблему? Тильдовцы молчат...

Comment: Скрипт tilda-map-1.0.min.js с какого домена тянете?

Comment: https://static.tildacdn.com/js/tilda-map-1.0.min.js

Comment: если взять карту через конструктор карт и закинуть html код на сайт тильды, то он работает. а если их собственный блок для карт - не работает... а их блок удобнее и проще настраивать и редактировать

Comment: В общем, получается, что вы сидите на одном домене, тянете скрипт со второго, а тот тянет скрипт с третьего. Сейчас так нельзя.